# Network issue on solana pay

Tags: transactions, solana-pay, phantom-wallet, network

when I scan the QR from Phantom wallet for sol transaction with my wifi connection it'working fine but when I switch to cellular network I am facing network issue.Could anyone explain me what is the issue here and how to solve it

Comment: Do other actions in the wallet work on cellular, like using the in-app browser and doing transactions there?

Comment: Yes I can tranasfer sol .